# How to run Unity 8 at Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: unity, lightdm, unity8, 17.04

When I try to launch Unity 8 from lightdm screen, it just hides my password form after I entered password and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. And nothing. It stays on the login screen. I can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and password form is showing again.
How to login to Unity 8? Should I install some packages?
3D drivers are installed.

Comment: How did you install Unity 8? Was it upgraded when you upgraded the Ubuntu release?

Comment: @DavidFoerster it was fresh install. Unity 8 was installed during system setup.

Comment: Unity 8 doesn't work with proprietary graphics drivers (and never will, the project is dead for all intended purposes).

Comment: Project not dead. It live by name Yunit.